# PHP Find Previous String Position

Tags: php, string, find, position

Is there a way that I can search a variable starting from a given position and find the start position of a string that is in the variable backwards from the given start position.

So for example if I initially do `$getstart = strpos($contents, 'position', 0);`

I then want to do `$getprevpos = prevstrpos($contents, 'previous token', $getstart);`

Obviously there is no such function as `prevstrpos` but I hope you get what I mean.

Example text area (terrible example I now):
Here is an example where I want to find the previous token once I have found the start position of a text string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `strrpos( substr($contents, 0, $getstart), 'previous token')`

Comment: I don't see how that can work - as substr is string , start, length then your example will just give me the first position of 'previous token' from position 0. What I need is the first one backwards from my start position.

Comment: I modified the code to use strrpos which will give you the last occurence of 'previous token' - I don't know for sure if I understood correctly your needs. The substr makes sure that the search is taking place in the string up to the position of 'position'.

Comment: Ahh ok gotcha.... I need to open my eyes... strRpos not strpos. Yep that'll do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something wrong with strrpos()?  If 'offset' is negative:  "Negative values will stop searching at the specified point prior to the end of the string."

Comment: But as there can be multiple occurences of 'previous token' from the start of the string I don't see how using a negative offset can help. I want to search backwards from the offset position and get the first occurence that I come accross not the first from position 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. I think it should would for all cases but you should probly test it a bit. Might be a bug here and there but you get the idea. Reverse everything and do a strpos on the reversed string

```
prevstrpos( $contents, $token, $start )
{
  $revToken = strrev($token);
  $revStart = strlen($token) - $start;
  $revContent = strrev($content);
  $revFoundPos = strpos( $revContent, $revToken, $revStart );
  if( $revFoundPos != -1 )
  {
    $foundPos = strlen($token) - $revFoundPos;
  }
  else
  {
    $foundPos = -1;
  }
  return $foundPos;
}
```